# How to debug "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in <file> on line <number>"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this kind of error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\showdata.php on line 29"

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="db1";
$tbname="student";

$conn= new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("connection failed:".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql="SELECT name,mail,password,subject,gender,city FROM $tbname";
$result=$conn->query($sql)===true;
if($result){
//if ($result === false) { die(mysqli_error($conn)); }
//{

//}
//echo $results;
//echo $sql;
//if(!$result)
//{echo "aa";
if($result-> num_rows >0)
{
    while($row= $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "id:".$row["id"]."name:".$row["name"]."email".$row["email"]."password".$row["password"]."subject".$row["subject"]."gender".$row["gender"]."city".$row["city"]."<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}//}
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: the sql references `mail` as a selected field yet the php uses `email`

Comment: Which line is line 29 as specified in the error message?

Comment: @RamRaider That would give another notice or warning, not the named one.

Comment: This might be another issue: `$result-> num_rows` should be `$result->num_rows`.

Answer (score 1):

For your error ,

You put Boolean value in `$result` and expect its query result

Change here.

```
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if($result === true){
```

and before getting error for `$row["email"]` ensure that what is column name in your db table and what you are expecting.

Comment: `if($result)` is perfectly ok to test that. Comes out the same as your suggestion, since `if(FALSE)` is evaluated to FALSE.

Comment: @arkascha:  May be I didn't interpreted this. can you please explain what it does, `$result=$conn->query($sql)===true;`   I am will remove my ans

Comment: Ohk now I understand , I should remove that part. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand! Sorry! You should mention in your answer that `$result=$conn->query($sql)===true;` explicitly sets the value of `$result` to `TRUE` which obviously breaks the result of the code. Sorry for not realizing that earlier.